# Why do I only have 1 gold badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I have 2 questions with over 10k views (one with 10k and the other with over 40k) but have only received the gold popular question badge once.

Comment: Probably should also mention  that those badges are awarded every so often (nightly or weekly, I forget which), so you won't get the badge the instant you get the 10000th view, but some hours or days later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the second one has only 9,945, 55 short of the 10,000 needed.

Your profile shows "10k" because the numbers there are rounded, not truncated.

Comment: Oh, ok thank you Federico.